# compare for loop in python and in java/c

Tags: java, python, c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to convert the following code from Java to Python and this is the input:

```
commonPrefix("", "something"), //one string is ""
commonPrefix("some", "something"), " //for loop finishes
commonPrefix("someother", "something") //for loop breaks
```

Java/C++ code:

```
String commonPrefix(String str1, String str2){
  int len = min(len(str1), len(str2));
  for (int i = 0; i< len; i++) {
      if (str1[i] != str2[i]) break;
  }
  return str1.substring(0,i);
}
```

If I write python code, it looks like I have to deal with three cases separately instead of combining them in the same line?

Python code:

```
def commonPrefix(str1, str2):  
    len = min(len(str1), len(str2))
    if len == 0: return "" #cannot combine with line7
    for i in range(len):
        if str1[i] != str2[i]:
            return str1[0:i]
    return str1[0:i+1] #line7:i is len-1, so have to use str1[0:i+1]
```

Comment: You messed up everything. In Java you can't get a character from string like you are trying. This code will not even compile.

Comment: You don't have `String` type in C++ unless you wrote it yourself or got it from a library.

Comment: I am using Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My three cents

```
def common_prefix( s1, s2 ):
    i, l = 0, min( len( s1 ), len( s2 ) )
    while i < l and s1[i] == s2[i]: i += 1
    return s1[:i]

print( "\"{}\"".format( common_prefix( "", "something" ) ) )
print( "\"{}\"".format( common_prefix( "some", "something" ) ) )
print( "\"{}\"".format( common_prefix( "someother", "something" ) ) )
```

Comment: i c, you use while to bypass the index issue I am confused.

Comment: Why accept the answer if it confuses you? It doesnt even almost answer the question that was asked. It's a solution to the name of your method @user389955

Comment: @AK47 I think it is not the answer that confuses. It is using the index in the original code that confused.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow its BigDaddyRep favourtism. I bet he's confused by your answer, it's tough to comprehend for Python newbies & this guy is struggling to write for loops.. /salt

Comment: @AK47. I am learning python so I am trying to rewrite some java code using python. I thought "for i in range(length)" and "for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)" are the same thing. until I found that: using python, when out of for loop of "for i in range(length)", i will equal to length-1, while in java/c, when out of for loop of "for (int i = 0; i< length; i++), i will equal to length, so I need to take care of the index differently. If using while loop, the index is handled the same way.

Comment: Your question title asks to compare for loops and this solution contains a while loop with no explanation in the answer. You clicked accept because he has 125k rep, this is Ok. Welcome to StackOverflow, please consider that in the future people will find you question when they search keywords, so a direct answer to the question should be accepted. Although this code is very clean and works perfect, this answer is a solution to your method, not to your actual question

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to slice for your final return statement, if it reaches this point then the whole word has matched, so you can just return the whole word. As for checking if the word is empty, this will be caught if the `len(str1) == 0 or len(str2) == 0`, then your for loop wont run and you just need to return the smallest of both values

```
def commonPrefix(str1, str2):
    length = min(len(str1), len(str2))

    for i in range(length):
        if str1[i] != str2[i]:
            return str1[0:i]

    return min(str1, str2)

print(commonPrefix("something", "something"))
>> something
print(commonPrefix("someother", "something"))
>> some
print(commonPrefix("", "something"))
>> ""
print(commonPrefix("something", ""))
>> ""
```

Comment: u r right. case of empty string can be combined. in fact I was confused by another thing:the index issue of python. when out of for loop normally, i becomes length, while in java/c, when out of for loop normally, i becomes length+1, I think this is a big difference of python and java which I need to pay attention to.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is the first line in the function: `len = min(len(str1), len(str2))`. You are overwritting the len function with the result. I assume since you are doing this on the same line you are trying to use the len function, python thinks that the variable is not yet defined. Here is a example of how to fix it.

```
def commonPrefix(str1, str2):  
    min_length = min(len(str1), len(str2))
    for i in range(min_length):
        if str1[i] != str2[i]:
            return str1[:i]
    return str1
```

Comment: Also, python convention is to use snake_case for function names. So the function name should be `common_prefix`.

Comment: should return min(str1, str2)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have adequately answered the question, but a list comprehension can do the same thing with `takewhile` from `itertools`.

```
from itertools import takewhile

def common_prefix(s1, s2):
    return ''.join([c[0] for c in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(s1, s2))])
```

Comment: good to know how to use lambda and takewhile. in fact I was confused by another thing: the index issue of python. when out of for loop normally, i becomes length, while in java/c, when out of for loop normally, i becomes length+1, I think this is a big difference of python and java I need to pay attention to.